# Java File Handling writing in File not 'overwriting'

Tags: java, file-handling

i am doing basic `File Handling` in Java.  what i want is that once i run my code and `.txt` file is created in specified location  and some  Text is writtern there , now next time when i write something it should not  `OVERWRITE` it , but should start ahead of it .. For example first time i  wrote  "Hello  java" , next time when i run  program and try to write "Java is good "  file should have something like this    "Hello java " "java is good",,
Right now  i am doing  this

```
    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("c:\\test.txt"));
    bf.write("Hello Java");
    bf.close();// and so on .
```

now when next time i run and type

```
    BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("c:\\test.txt"));
    bf.write("Java is good ");
    bf.close();// and so on .
```

it should not overwrite  , So pleas guide mt about it . Thanks in advance

Comment: Your text contradicts your example. You say 'when i write something it should not OVERWRITE it , but should start ahead of it', but your example has the second data *after* the first data. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a boolean argument with value 'true' to the FileWriter constructor.

[FileWriter#FileWriter(File, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Comment: I see it now, the first sentence of the OP's question threw me off, I thought he was talking about pre-pending. +1 when I get more votes in 47 minutes :)

Comment: I also got the 'ahead' wrong, but his example text explained a case of appending ...

Comment: Sorry for bad description but this was  the problem  that @ChriWeis answered . Its solved thanks